# $\mathbb{Z}$ under finite-complement topology [CSIR-2015]

Tags: general-topology

> Consider the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers with the topology $\tau$ in which a subset is closed iff it is empty, or $\mathbb{Z}$, or finite. Which of the following is true?
>
> 1. $\tau$ is the subspace topology induced from the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.
> 2. $\mathbb{Z}$ is compact in the topology $\tau$.
> 3. $\mathbb{Z}$ is hausdorff in the topology $\tau$.
> 4. Every infinite subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in the topology $\tau$.

I think 1 is true since any closed set in $\tau$ is $\mathbb{Z}\cap [a,b]$(or a finite union of these sets of this type) a,b integers(for finite sets) or the entire real line when the closed set is entire
$\mathbb{Z}$ .

Since any non-trivial open set is basically $\mathbb{Z}$-{a finite set of integers}.

3 is false because given two integers $a,b$ if i try to look for two disjoint open sets $U_a$,$U_b$  they will always have a infinite number of points in their intersection.

4 is true since if i take any open set in $\tau$(which is of the above type) it  must intersect a infinite subset of $\mathbb{Z}$.

I am not able to say anything about compactness. Further are all of the above reasoning correct?

Comment: Closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ is not necessarily a finite union of $[a,b]$.

Comment: How was the exam overall ?How much did you score?@Prayagdeep

Comment: @learnmore i guess  i will end up with a tip over 100.Is this the right place to continue this discussion...i have some more doubts on the questions, is there another place where we can discuss..?

Comment: A few years late, but in case anyone else is wondering: MSE has a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com), which would be the best place for discussing contests after they've completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 is not true:

Since when $\mathbb Z$ is given subspace topology it becomes discrete i.e every one point sets are both closed and open which is not true with $\tau$.

$\tau $ is compact since if you consider the open cover $\{U_{\alpha}:\alpha \in I\}$ then $\mathbb Z\setminus U_{\alpha}$ is finite and hence the remaining points can be covered with finite number of elements from $I$

Rest are fine

Answer (score 1):

(1) is false.  The subspace topology on $\Bbb Z$ induced by the standard topology on $\Bbb R$ is the discrete topology.  So, $\{1\}$ is open in the subspace topolobgy, but not in the finite complement topology.